# (IONIC SLIDER) How to set default first slide when you get back from other tabs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, slider

i have a project ionic used 3 tabs

- Home
- Maps
- About(Slide)

My problem is when i using slide until the last slide and i choose home tabs or maps and comeback again to slide tabs, it's show the last slide not first slide.

My about.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      <div text-center>Bantuan</div>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="tutorial-page">

  <ion-slides pager>
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
      <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image"/>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>

</ion-content>
```

and this is my about.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {

  slides = [
   {
     title: "Welcome to the Docs!",
     description: "The <b>Ionic Component Documentation</b> showcases a number of useful components that are included out of the box with Ionic.",
     image: "assets/imgs/bantu1.png",
   },
   {
     title: "What is Ionic?",
     description: "<b>Ionic Framework</b> is an open source SDK that enables developers to build high quality mobile apps with web technologies like HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.",
     image: "assets/imgs/bantu2.png",
   },
   {
     title: "What is Ionic Cloud?",
     description: "The <b>Ionic Cloud</b> is a cloud platform for managing and scaling Ionic apps with integrated services like push notifications, native builds, user auth, and live updating.",
     image: "assets/imgs/bantu3.png",
   },
   {
     image: "assets/imgs/bantu4.png",
   },
   {
     image: "assets/imgs/bantu5.png",
   },
   {
     image: "assets/imgs/bantu6.png",
   },
   {
     image: "assets/imgs/bantu7.png",
   },
   {
     image: "assets/imgs/bantu8.png",
   }
 ];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

how can i get the first slide again when comeback to slide tabs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/#slideTo), you have to use initialSlide ,using the index of your slide when you enter in the view.

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
   // Set initial slides value.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helped me. I add index and use this.slider.slideTo(0);